# Guest OS Support for VMWare ESXi 4 on an IBM xSeries 366 Server

Tags: virtual-machines, 64-bit, ibm, vmware-esxi

I was able to install Windows Server 2008 R2 without a problem (which requires 64 bit) on an IBM xSeries 366 server. But I also found out the x366 doesn't support HAV so adding the Hyper-V role is out.

I saw that the x366 is in the HCL for VMWare's ESXi and it installed/configured without a glitch.

I tried to export a Win 2008 R2 virtual from workstation into ESXi which was going fine right up until the step where it starts moving the virtual disk to the server. At that point i was greeted with an error that it couldn't migrate x64 to x32.

I tried to create a new virtual machine in ESXi and selected Windows Server 2008 R2. When it booted from the iso I was greeted with an error that x64 can't install on x32 hardware.

So, I'm trying to figure out if I've done something wrong or if x64 guest support just simply isn't available in that box? I've tried looking everywhere that I could find but am coming up empty handed for my specific instance: Will Win 2008R2 run as a VMWare ESXi guest on an IBM xSeries 366?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a restriction that applies to ESX4 and any CPU that does not support hardware virtualization - you cannot virtualize 64bit Guests on Intel CPU's without enabling hardware virtualization.

The x366 supports Hardware Virtualization (VTx in Intel terms) and if they have the Dual Core Paxville MP Xeons (the 70xx series Xeons) then it can be enabled. If you have those CPU's you can get this to work but if your 366 has the older single core Potomac Xeon's you will not be able to do this because they do not support VTx.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Intel VT or AMD Virtualization features are enabled in the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

On older models of IBM X366, Xeon were high frequency but single core. Later models used dual core processors, VT-capable.

You can refer to http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/xbc/cog/Withdrawn/x366/x366aag.html to check with you model reference.

IBM x366 ref. 8863-3RY and 4RY should be VT capable.